# Saving in sharedPrefs variable permanently

Tags: java, android

i've got a Facebook login and i need to save variable of user, userid and email in my shared prefs to utilize them in my second activity that has got a fragment in another class.

here is my Facebook login onSuccess method:

```
 public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                        // App code
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login successful" + loginResult.getAccessToken().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                                loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                                new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onCompleted(
                                            JSONObject object,
                                            GraphResponse response) {
                                        // Application code

                                        //textView.setText(response.toString());

                                        JSONObject j_user = response.getJSONObject();
                                        try {
                                             id = j_user.getString("id");
                                             email = j_user.getString("email");
                                             name = j_user.getString("name");
                                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                        }
                                        Log.i("string", response.toString());
                                        Log.i("string", id);
                                        Log.i("string", email);
                                        Log.i("string", name);
                                    }
                                });

                        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                        parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email");
                        request.setParameters(parameters);
                        request.executeAsync();
                        SavePreferences("id", id);
                        SavePreferences("email", email);
                        SavePreferences("name", name);
                    }
```

Here is my save preferences method and the "gotootheractivity" button

```
private void SavePreferences(String key, String value){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
   SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString(key, value);
    editor.commit();
    //Intent sd=new Intent(this,SampleActivity.class);
    //startActivity(sd);
}

public void goToEvents(View view)
{
    Toast.makeText(this, name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Intent intent = new Intent(FbLoginActivity.this, SampleActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

in the first activity the name that i'm "Toast" works,
here is the code of the second activity :

```
  private void LoadPreferences(){
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        String  name = sharedPreferences.getString("name", "0") ;
        String  email = sharedPreferences.getString("email", "0") ;
        String  id = sharedPreferences.getString("id", "0") ;
        Toast.makeText(this, name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Toast.makeText(this, id, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Toast.makeText(this, email, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

I'm using this method after the setContentView(), and the "Toast" doesn't works, they all displays "0", and when i close the app and i click on my button the first button too displays me "   " , it seems that SharedPrefs aren't stored well..

Comment: Check if the `editor.commit()` method is actually saving your edits by printing the boolean it returns like this: `System.out.println(editor.commit());`. Then you know if it is even saving the preference or not, which might reduce the number of possible errors to check. Then update the question. Also, as a side note, you should probably have constants for all your keys, i.e. save them as public static final variables, for example something like this for the email key: `public static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";`, so that you can be sure that you haven't done any typos when you get errors.

Comment: the logcat display this : " I/System.out﹕ true" but the variables now are "name" "email" and "id" when i reopen the app,
i saved  them to " public static String KEY_NAME = "name";" because if i put the final property android studio tells me to change them into not final variable (only in Facebook method where i have try @TheddESTROYER12

Comment: Strange. 'll take a look at it later.

Comment: you should put the `SavePreferences()` invocation inside your `GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback.onCompleted()` method